# Customizing Zuul url endpoints for services in JHipster

Tags: jhipster, netflix-zuul

I have a group of microservices, called "client-Foo", where Foo is the name for some particular third-party client.

Using those names as-is creates some really ugly endpoint urls, so I want to translate them to a much nicer hierarchal form.

I added a custom `PatternServiceRouteMapper` that take  the serviceId `client-Foo` and turns it into the url `client/Foo`.

This gives the url I want, but also breaks the service mapping because it *also* changes the registered serviceId to `client/Foo`; thus, when Zuul goes to route it fails because there *is* no `client/Foo` service, its id is `client-Foo`!

I cannot hardcode any paths because the application requires an arbitrary number of different "client-*" services.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at [ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration.java), you can see that you can replace some beans to achieve your goal and in particular you should consider providing your own implementation of `RouteLocator` interface or extend `DiscoveryClientRouteLocator` class.
Your service instances could also register in Eureka server with additional data in metadataMap that your `RouteLocator` could use.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add a configuration defined   Zuul route :

```
zuul:
    routes:
        client-foo: /foo/**
```

Also I would advise against having a dash in a service-id as it can confuse the config server api (in /config/foo-profile.yml where profile is the spring profile for which you want to get the config).

Comment: Configuring each route manuall in a configuration file is a no-go.